# Writing onto a CSV column on applescript

Tags: csv, applescript

So I'm creating a script in AppleScript that needs to write onto a column in a CSV. I've already read from the CSV and I have code on how to write onto a CSV but it doesn't write at all. I want to write on column 22. At the moment, I can read from that column but I'm not sure how to edit the column. Or is there a way to edit a certain box in excel like A3 to say this "Yes". I've attached my code below.

```
set theFile to (choose file)
set f to read theFile

-- break the file into paragraphs (c.f. rows)
repeat with row in (paragraphs of f)
    -- parse the row into comma-delimited fields
    set fields to parseCSV(row as text)
    -- now you have your data:
    set verifyAccountStatus to item 22 of fields
    set theResult to writeTo(verifyAccountStatus, "Yes", text, true)

end repeat

on parseCSV(theText)
    set {od, my text item delimiters} to {my text item delimiters, ","}
    set parsedText to text items of theText
    set my text item delimiters to od
    return parsedText
end parseCSV

on writeTo(targetFile, theData, dataType, apendData)
    -- targetFile is the path to the file you want to write
    -- theData is the data you want in the file.
    -- dataType is the data type of theData and it can be text, list, record etc.
    -- apendData is true to append theData to the end of the current contents of the file or false to overwrite it
    try
        set openFile to open for access file targetFile with write permission
        if apendData is false then set eof of openFile to 0
        write theData to openFile starting at eof as dataType
        close access openFile
        return true
    on error
        try
            close access file targetFile
        end try
        return false
    end try
end writeTo
```

EDIT:
For some reason it isn't working when I run this.

```
set theFile to (choose file)
set openFile to open for access theFile with write permission
do shell script "awk -F, '$1 ~ /Line 7/{$22=\"hello\"} 1' openFile"
close access openFile
```

It says it can't open file openFile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe consider doing this using `awk` which is built-in to OS X anyway. Say your file is called `file.csv` and it is comma-separated and looks like this:

```
Line 0,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,16
Line 1,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,44
Line 2,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,93
Line 3,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,96
Line 4,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,19
Line 5,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,77
Line 6,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,30
Line 7,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,30
Line 8,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,1
Line 9,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,96
```

If you run this `awk` script in the Terminal, it will change all the `field22` entries to "Hello"

```
awk -F, '{$22="hello"}1' OFS=, file.csv
```

and give you this:

```
Line 0,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,hello,f23,f24,16
Line 1,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,hello,f23,f24,44
Line 2,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,hello,f23,f24,93
Line 3,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,hello,f23,f24,96
Line 4,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,hello,f23,f24,19
Line 5,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,hello,f23,f24,77
Line 6,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,hello,f23,f24,30
Line 7,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,hello,f23,f24,30
Line 8,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,hello,f23,f24,1
Line 9,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,hello,f23,f24,96
```

If you want that in a new file, just redirect the output like this:

```
awk -F, '{$22="hello"}1' OFS=, file.csv > newfile.csv
```

You can call this from Applescript using:

```
do shell script "awk -F, '{$22=\"hello\"} 1' file.csv > newFile.csv"
```

If you want the user to choose a file from a dialog window, then your filename will be in an Applescript variable - in your example it is called `theFile`. You will then need to convert this to a filename that the shell and `awk` understand, and quote it and pass it to the shell something like this:

```
do shell script "awk -F, '{$22=\"hello\"} 1'  & quoted form of POSIX path of theFile & " > /tmp/a"
```

If you only want to change field 22 on lines that contain "77" anywhere on them, do this:

```
awk -F, '/77/ {$22="hello"} 1' file.csv

Line 0,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,16
Line 1,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,44
Line 2,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,93
Line 3,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,96
Line 4,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,19
Line 5 field2 field3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 f11 f12 f13 f14 f15 f16 f17 f18 f19 f20 f21 hello f23 f24 77
Line 6,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,30
Line 7,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,30
Line 8,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,1
Line 9,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,96
```

If you only want to change field22 on lines where field 1 matches "Line 7", you can do this:

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ /Line 7/ {$22="hello"} 1' file.csv
Line 0,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,16
Line 1,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,44
Line 2,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,93
Line 3,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,96
Line 4,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,19
Line 5,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,77
Line 6,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,30
Line 7 field2 field3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 f11 f12 f13 f14 f15 f16 f17 f18 f19 f20 f21 hello f23 f24 30
Line 8,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,1
Line 9,field2,field3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,96
```

**Note:**

The `-F,` just tells `awk` that input fields are separated by commas. The `OFS=,` tells `awk` to separate output fields by commas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can try that, but do you know whether it's possible to edit just one of the values in that column?

Comment: Should be. How do we know which one?

Comment: I have added some more tips to help you be able to be more precise in your edits :-)

Comment: Thank you! For some reason it isn't working when I run this.
     set theFile to (choose file)
     do shell script awk -F, '$1 ~ /Line 7/ {$22="hello"} 1' theFile
It says it's expecting the end of line but found ","

Comment: It's very hard to read code in comments - can you click `edit` under your original question and add all info there please? I guess your quoting is incorrect...

Comment: I have added an example into my answer - you basically need double quotes arround the whole command and you need to escape any double quotes within the command using a backslash in front - no need to escape single quotes.

Comment: I have added some more explanation - please have another look. Do you want to overwrite the existing file, or create a new file?

Comment: I want to edit the existing file, aka just fill in the boxes in field 22 of that file on run time

Comment: I want to overwrite the box in column 22, row 2 (if you open the CSV in excel)